# What's wrong, Worked for the first time

Tags: angularjs

**Directive:**

```
'use strict';
var foodMeApp = angular.module('foodMeApp', ['ngResource', 'breeze.angular.q']);

foodMeApp.directive('angularReleases', function(){
    return {
    restrict :'EA',
    link : function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('http://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/commits')
            .success(function(commits) {
                $scope.commits = commits
            })

    },
    template : '<ul>'+
                 '<li ng-repeat="commit in commits">'+
                 '{{ commit.commit.committer.date | date }}'+
                 '<a ng-href="https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/{{commit.sha}}">{{ commit.sha }}</a>'+
                 '{{ commit.commit.message }}'+
                 '</li>'+
                '</ul>'
    }

});
```

**And in view:**

```
<angular-releases />
```

And the **file is included in the index.html file after angular.js file** , It worked for the first time, after that , it is showing the error:

[image]

Can any body also suggest me some tricks/tips on how to analyze/backtrace the error, like in this error i can only understand '$http.get(...) is undefined'. rest others i do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject $http into the directive

```
foodMeApp.directive('angularReleases',['$http', function($http){
    return {
    link : function($scope){
    },    
}]);
```

You main problem is that second parameter of link function is `element`, which doesn't have `get` method.

link takes a function with the following signature, `function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... }` where:

- `scope` is an Angular scope object.
- `element` is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.
- `attrs` is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their corresponding attribute values.

Comment: Yes you are correct, i forgot the syntax of link function, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject $http into the directive:

```
foodMeApp.directive('angularReleases', function($http){
```